# Different interword spacing in english and french

Tags: fonts, spacing, babel, languages

I'm making a document with babel  and monotype font. 
I made some settings to have a specific alignement but I have problem when using another language.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{book}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\spaceskip=1.0\fontdimen2\font plus 0\fontdimen3\font minus 0\fontdimen4\font

\begin{document}
\obeyspaces
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{-2\fontcharwd\font`A}
\setlength{\leftskip}{2\fontcharwd\font`A}

\foreignlanguage{english}{%
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam dapibus.
}

\foreignlanguage{french}{%
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam dapibus.
}

\end{document}
```

When I switch to english, I have a missing space before the `:` character:

[image]

**Do you know how to have the same spacing around a `:` in french and english?**

Comment: Which engine are you using? `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: The space isn't missing in the English. There shouldn't be one there - it is incorrect English punctuation to include a space before, as well as after, the colon. French and English have different punctuation rules.

Comment: in English, it looks odd to have a space before the `:` but if you want a space before `:` simply have a space before `:` in the source. It is just in the French style that `:` is redefined to add a space even if there was no space originally.

Comment: If you had used `\ttfamily` to activate the (suitably set-up) monospace font, `babel-french` would not have added the space. But I would recommend here `\frenchsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}` and then no space is added. Then you can have same source for both languages.

Comment: @cfr what do you mean, it's incorrect to have a space after the colon: that can't be right, can it?

Comment: @thymaro It is incorrect to have a space **before** the colon. You're right you need one after, but you don't want two in English, as you do in French. I meant that it is incorrect to have one before in addition to correctly having one after and not that it is incorrect to have a space either before or after.

Comment: @cfr I'm relieved. I was afraid I'd have to go give my English teachers an update on modern English punctuation :D

Comment: @thymaro :-). My comment was ambiguous, but I only realised that after you commented. I guess I was just taking for granted that a space was needed **after**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is that English doesn't put a space before punctuation like French does.

## Update for LuaLaTeX support

Here's a go doing this in a way that supports both `lualatex` and `xelatex`. I have used `\raggedright` since without this you get overfull boxes. And I set the default font to be monospaced in a slightly nicer way.

I still call `\extrasfrench` from within `\extrasenglish`. But I also set the `lua` variable `FR_ca` to be the same as `\the\l@english` (`=0`). The `lua` function that does the punctuation spacing checks if the current language is either `FR_fr` or `FR_ca`. By changing one of these to be `0` (for English), we can get French punctuation for both languages. Finally, I added `\frenchsetup{OriginalTypewriter=true}` so that if you use `\ttfamily` or `\texttt` it will still work. (By default `french-babel` does not automatically adjust the punctuation in these cases.)

Also, note that you have specified a `13pt`. The book class only supports `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. So `13pt` simply gives you `10pt` which is the default.

Output is the same for both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\frenchsetup{OriginalTypewriter=true}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \extrasfrench
}
\makeatletter
\ifx\directlua\@undefined\else
  \directlua{FR_ca = \the\l@english}
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
\section*{Français}
\today{}

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit
amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam
dapibus.

\selectlanguage{english}

\section*{English with French punctuation}
\today{}

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit
amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam
dapibus.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Original XeLaTeX only answer

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to change this behaviour with `lualatex`, but this seems to do what you want with `xelatex`.

I've left out all your spacing commands so you can see that the hyphenation rules (and strings) still change, but the punctuation rules stay French.

Basically, I just call `\extrasfrench` inside of `\extrasenglish`. As far as I can see `\extrasfrench` doesn't do much else other than handle punctuation. (But I might be wrong.)

BTW, there is no `13pt` argument for the `book` class.

I also made `french` the default language, as this seems to make sense if you want French style punctuation everywhere.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \extrasfrench
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\section*{Français}

\today{}

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit
amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam
dapibus.

\selectlanguage{english}

\section*{English}

\today{}

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit
amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam
dapibus.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You might want to add that `13pt` will get you `10pt` font and not `12pt`, as you might hope or expect :).

Comment: @cfr, yes, I guess that is worth mentioning.

Comment: Can't upvote again, though - sorry :(.

Answer (score 3):

Deactivate extra spacing around high punctuation in French (so that if you want it, you must type it in yourself in the source).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\frenchsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font\relax

\begin{document}
\obeyspaces
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{-2\fontcharwd\font`A}
\setlength{\leftskip}{2\fontcharwd\font`A}

\foreignlanguage{english}{%
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam dapibus.
}

\foreignlanguage{french}{%
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna, tincidunt, consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum, Nam dapibus.
}

\end{document}
```

By the way, `babel-french` patches `\texttt` and `\ttfamily` to not insert extra spacing when using monospace font, but in this example, no use is made of these LaTeX macros.

[image]